# Multiple commands in Docker CMD directive

Tags: docker

Not understanding what is happening when I try to execute two commands at runtime via CMD directive in `Dockerfile. I assumed that this should work:

```
CMD ["/etc/init.d/nullmailer", "start", ";", "/usr/sbin/php5-fpm"]
```

But it's not working. Container has not started. So I had to do it like this:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/etc/init.d/nullmailer start ; /usr/sbin/php5-fpm"]
```

I don't understand. Why is that? Why first line is not the right way? Can somebody explain me these "CMD shell format vs JSON format, etc" stuff. In simple words.

Just to note - the same was with `command:` directive in `docker-compose.yml`, as expected.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I believe the difference might be because the second command does shell processing while the first does not. Per the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), there are the `exec` and `shell` forms. Your first command is an `exec` form. The `exec` form does not expand environment variables while the `shell` form does. It is possible that by using the `exec` form the command is failing due to its dependence on shell processing. You can check this by running `docker logs CONTAINERID`

Your second command, the shell form, is equivalent to -

`CMD /etc/init.d/nullmailer start ; /usr/sbin/php5-fpm`

Excerpts from the documentation -

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, `CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on `$HOME`. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo", "$HOME" ]`.

Comment: Probably command failed because of environment variables. Should I still use this `exec` form, as it is the preferred form? Why it is preferred? Or should I use simpler `shell` form?

Comment: It failed because executing one command after another is a shell function. Environment variables is a red herring.

Comment: If you are running multiple services in Docker, I would recommend using a process manager like supervisor. That way you launch only supervisord under the CMD section and it will take care of starting the services. You can check for details here - https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: This is an exact article I was just reading :) Thanks.

Comment: I still don't understand why you need to do `CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo", "$HOME"]`. Why not `CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $HOME"]` or, for that matter, `CMD ["sh -c echo $HOME"]`?

Answer (score 72):

Don't make it hard on yourself. Just create a bash file "start.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/command2 param1
/usr/bin/command1
```

in your Dockerfile do:

```
ADD start.sh /
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

Comment: While I completely agree to KISS, this unfortunately might impact the performance in older versions of docker and/or unnecessary increase the size of the built image. This is because you're creating two layers with `ADD` and `RUN`, have a look at [the best practices, minimize the number of layers](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers).

Comment: My understanding is that this will run the script in a shell, causing the any resultant processes (e.g. webserver) to be a child process of the shell, and will not be forwarded SIGTERM, thus preventing those processes from gracefully exiting

Answer (score 12):

The json syntax of `CMD` (and `RUN` and `ENTRYPOINT`) pass the arguments to the kernel directly as an exec syscall. There is no separating of the command from the arguments by spaces, escaping of quotes, IO redirection, variable substitution, piping between commands, running multiple commands, etc, in the exec syscall. The syscall only takes the executable to run and list of arguments to pass to that executable, and it runs it.

Characters like `$` to expand variables, `;` to separate commands,  (space) to separate arguments, `&&` and `||` to chain commands, `>` for output redirection, `|` to pipe between commands, etc, are all features of the shell and need something like `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` to interpret and implement them.

---

If you switch to the string syntax of `CMD`, docker will run your command with a shell:

```
CMD /etc/init.d/nullmailer start ; /usr/sbin/php5-fpm
```

Otherwise, your second syntax does the exact same thing:

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "/etc/init.d/nullmailer start ; /usr/sbin/php5-fpm"]
```

---

Note that I do not recommend running multiple commands this way inside of a container since there is no error handling if your first command fails, especially if it runs in the background. You also leave a shell running as pid 1 inside the container which will break signal handling, resulting in a 10 second delay and ungraceful kill of your container by docker. The signal handling can be mitigated by using the shell `exec` command:

```
CMD /etc/init.d/nullmailer start ; exec /usr/sbin/php5-fpm
```

However, handling processes silently failing in the background requires you switch to some kind of multi-process manager like supervisord, or preferably breakup your application into multiple containers and deploy them with something like docker-compose.

Comment: This is brilliant, `exec` is the solution to common problem of not being able to stop the container. Also, the common scenario is that you are forced to switch to Docker but you still want to run your app + some background service, such as Datadog agent. this above is a good solution solution if you don't want to go with a full docker cluster with separate containers running just to be able to collect metrics or traces for DD.

Answer (score 2):

In Docker compose, this can be done as the following example:

```
command: ["sh", "-c", "
    apt update && apt install -y libldap-common;
    cp /ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/;
    update-ca-certificates;
    exec apache2-foreground
  "]
```

The `exec` will switch the context of the main executable to apache2-forground.

Answer (score 1):

I guess first command fails because in DOCKER CMD form, only the first parameter is executed, the rest is fed into this command.

The second form works because all commands seperated with ";" are fed into sh command, which executes them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should put semi comma after "start"

instead of using

```
CMD ["/etc/init.d/nullmailer", "start", ";", "/usr/sbin/php5-fpm"]
```

try

```
CMD ["/etc/init.d/nullmailer", "start", "/usr/sbin/php5-fpm"]
```

as docker uses "sh -c", above command will be executed as below

```
/etc/init.d/nullmailer start
/etc/init.d/nullmailer /usr/sbin/php5-fpm
```

Comment: The json syntax does not run commands with a shell, there is not `sh -c` in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For example, imagine you have two python commands to run `python init_reset.py` and `python app.py`. Then using CMD, you can combine the two commands with the single command

```
CMD python init_reset.py ; python app.py
```

Comment: You left out the brackets. Can we create valid syntax without the square brackets?

Comment: Yes @mr.zog, we can.

Answer (score 0):

I found you can also do this in the Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT command && \
  command_2 && \
  another_command
```

You can probably substitute `CMD` for `ENTRYPOINT` and be ok - I just didn't try it. I found that the commands are executed in order and each command finishes before the next one starts, but if one of the commands (`command_2` for example) disconnected itself from the terminal and commands after it needed it to be finished before they ran you might run into some issues.